# Doctrine won't generate migration for new entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, sylius

Good day,
I have created new entity:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Inveocz\CMS\Entity;
    
    class BannerCategory implements BannerCategoryInterface
    {
        
        /** @var int|null */
        protected $id;
    
        /** @return int|null */
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

and xml mapping for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <mapped-superclass name="Inveocz\CMS\Entity\BannerCategory" table="inveocz_cms_banner_category">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
    </mapped-superclass>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

There is issues, that doctrine have registered this new entity, but running

```
    doctrine:migration:diff
```

won't generate any new migration in my project. Before that generating it for any other entity was fine.
Also when I run:

```
    doctrine:schema:validate
```

both schema and mapping are valid.
Same with:

```
    doctrine:mapping:info
```

will tell me that my "Inveocz\CMS\Entity\BannerCategory" is registered by doctrine.

Symfony: 4.4.18

PHP: 7.4.9

doctrine.yaml:

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: UTF8
    
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: xml
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Resources/config/doctrine/model'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
    
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    date: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
                    month: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                    year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
                numeric_functions:
                    round: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Round
```

Running:

```
    doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

won't help and droping my docker containers won't help either.
Can anyone give me hint what could possibly be wrong?
Thank much for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML map your entity as **mapped superclass**. This is not entity that really exists in database and can be only **inherited** by others.

Use this XML mapping to map entity that can be persisted and retrieved from DB:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
  <entity name="Inveocz\CMS\Entity\BannerCategory" table="inveocz_cms_banner_category">
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
         <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
     </id>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much for help. That was such stupid mistake.